# Setting a new object equal to another specific object

Tags: java, object

I'm writing my own ArrayList class at the moment and have initialized a list of cards in a deck. With the ArrayList class comes several instance methods, specifically one in which I give a specific object and expect a return message of whether or not the list contains that object. The method is set up fine, yet the perplexing part for me is how I set up a way to find that specific object from the created list.

Below is the current set up I have in the client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList deck = new ArrayList();

    for (Card.Suits suit : Card.Suits.values())
        for (Card.Ranks rank : Card.Ranks.values())
            deck.add(new Card(suit, rank));

    Object obj1 = ...;
    boolean element_found = deck.isIn(obj1);
    if(element_found)
        System.out.println(obj1 + " is in the list");
    else
        System.out.println(obj1 + " isn't in the list... dang");
}
```

When it comes to the section where I want to initialize obj1 to a specific Card object from the created list, I'm not sure how to go about it. Is there some method in which I just type out obj1 = "Ace of Hearts" or something along those lines?

Because when it came to creating a similar list, yet that time composed of Integer objects, once I wanted to find out if an object was in a given list, I just set obj1 equal to the literal number I was searching for.

Also, just in case it is needed, here is the code for the "isIn" method and its complement method "find."

```
public ArrayList{
    public boolean isIn(Object ob){
        boolean ReturnValue = false;
        if(find(ob) != -1){
            ReturnValue = true;
        }
        return ReturnValue;
    }
    public int find(Object n){
        int ReturnValue = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            if(n.equals(list[i]))
                ReturnValue = i;
        }
        return ReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap as a helper to find the Object.

```
HashMap<String,Card> map = new HashMap<String,Card>();

for (Card.Suits suit : Card.Suits.values())
        for (Card.Ranks rank : Card.Ranks.values()) {
            Card card = new Card(suit, rank);
            deck.add(card);
            // key is a String to represent card
            // key can be "AH" => Ace of Heart
            // "TS" => Ten of Spade
            map.put(key, card);            
         }

 Object obj1 = map.get("5C"); // find 5 of Club
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement your `find()` method as the index of the deck array.

```
 boolean element_found = deck.isIn(obj1);
    if(element_found) {
        System.out.println(obj1 + " is in the list");
        deck[find(obj1)] = Card(suit, rank);
    }
    else
        System.out.println(obj1 + " isn't in the list... dang");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should of made it clear that isIn(Object n) was a method I created in the ArrayList class which was to be used to perform the check at hand.

Comment: In that case, it would probably be good to include the code for that method in your question. Perhaps the problem lies there.

Comment: I've made sure to add in the code for the isIn method and the find method it uses to work. Yet, my problem doesn't lie there. As I said, I just am perplexed as to what the syntax should be for me setting obj1 equal to some specific Card object from the deck list.

Comment: Ah! That actually helps a lot. Your question could probably use some re-wording to make it easier to understand what you meant, but now that you rephrased it and posted the code for the `find()` method you made; I'll edit my answer to what you need.